R_max algorithm doesn't converge to the right policy
I have a task where I need to implement an R_max algorithm with modified policy iteration over the frozen lake problem.
I first tried to just implement a regular modified policy iteration and it worked but when I tried to adjust it to r max requirements (using fake model with a fake state) it doesn't converge to the right policy.
Unfortunately I am also not sure where exactly the problem is.
I would really appreciate if you could have a look over my code and maybe spot a few mistakes.
import numpy as np

class Rmax:
    def __init__(self, env, r_max=2.5, gamma=0.95, k=20, num_iterations=5, epsilon=1e-6, iterations=30000):
        # init model basic data structure
        self.env = env
        self.num_states = env.observation_space.n + 1
        self.num_actions = env.action_space.n
        self.r_max = r_max
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.k = k
        self.num_iterations = num_iterations
        self.epsilon = epsilon
        self.iterations = iterations
  #init fake Tr table
        self.Tr = np.ones((self.num_states, self.num_actions, self.num_states))
        for state in range(self.num_states-1):
            for action in range(self.num_actions):
                for next_state in range(self.num_states - 1):
                    self.Tr[state][action][next_state] = 1/(self.num_states-1) # we assume transition to all real states in uniform distribution
    
        self.rewards = np.zeros((self.num_states, self.num_actions))
        for action in range(self.num_actions):
            self.rewards[self.num_states-1][action] = self.r_max # reward for fake state is 1 all other rewards are 0
    
        #counters
        self.state_action_counter = np.zeros((self.num_states, self.num_actions), dtype=int)
        self.state_action_state_counter = np.zeros((self.num_states, self.num_actions, self.num_states), dtype=int)

    #known table
    self.known = np.zeros((self.num_states, self.num_actions), dtype=bool)

    self.policy = np.zeros(self.num_states, dtype=int)

    #and 0 for all values
    self.values = np.ones(self.num_states)


    def train(self):
    # Training loop is Solve model discover new states and solve again
        for i in range(self.iterations):
            print(f'iteration: {i}/{self.iterations}')
            self.solve_model()
    
    
    def solve_model(self):
    # solving the model with MPI requires to steps policy evaluation and policy improvement
        self.policy_eval()
        stable = self.policy_improvement()
        # now we run policy till we  know
        changed = False
        done, truncated = False, False
        while not changed and not done and not truncated:
            state = self.env.reset()[0]
            action = self.policy[state]
            next_state, reward, done, truncated, info = self.env.step(action)
            self.state_action_counter[state][action] += 1
            self.state_action_state_counter[state][action][next_state] += 1
            if self.state_action_counter[state][action] >= self.k:
                self.known[state][action] = True
                changed = True
        self.update_model()
    
    def update_model(self):
        for state in range(self.num_states):
            for action in range(self.num_actions):
                if self.known[state][action]:
                    for next_state in range(self.num_states):
                        if self.state_action_state_counter[state][action][next_state] != 0:
                            self.Tr[state][action][next_state] = (
                                    self.state_action_state_counter[state][action][next_state] / self.state_action_counter[state][action])
                        else:
                            self.Tr[state][action] = np.ones(self.num_states) / self.num_states
    


    def policy_eval(self):
    # in MPI we do a limited number of policy evaluation
        for _ in range(self.num_iterations):
            new_values = self.values.copy()
            for state in range(self.num_states):
                action = self.policy[state]
                new_value = 0
                for next_state in range(self.num_states):
                    prob = self.Tr[state][action][next_state]
                    reward = self.rewards[state][action]
                    new_value += prob *(reward + self.gamma * self.values[next_state])
                new_values[state] = new_value
    
    
            #also if policy converged we can stop
            if np.max(np.abs(new_values - self.values)) < self.epsilon:
                self.values = new_values
                break
            self.values = new_values

    def policy_improvement(self):
        stable = True
        for state in range(self.num_states):
            old_action = self.policy[state]
            action_values = np.zeros( self.num_actions)
            for action in range(self.num_actions):
                for next_state in range(self.num_states):
                    prob = self.Tr[state][action][next_state]
                    reward = self.rewards[state][action]
                    action_values[action] += prob * (reward + self.gamma * self.values[next_state])
            best_action = np.argmax(action_values)
            self.policy[state] = best_action
            if old_action != best_action:
                stable = False
        return stable

I tried to play with the values go over the algorithm again but unfortunately didn't identify the problem.

I dont know if it will be much of an help to others but we tried to add negtive reward after each iteration to the state. I think it helped since the rewards where all 0 and we didnt gave any negtive reward it just tried to explore the same path over and over again
